# What is the nth derivative of log(g(x)) and without combinatorics?

Tags: derivatives, proof-writing

We know the nth derivative of $ f(x)=\log(x)$ being a clean

> $$f^{(n)}(x)= - \frac{(-1)^{n}x^{-n}}{(n-1)!},$$

but when you consider that you need the chain rule, what is the $n$th derivative for $ \log(g(x))$ and without a completely impractical$\binom{n}{k}$thrown in, only just algebraic operations and factorials of a single parameter just like the original $n$th derivative of $ \log(x)$?

Comment: What makes you expect such an expression exists?

Comment: What is so impractical and "unalgebraic" about $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$?

Comment: Try to see the Faà di Bruno's formula, maybe you can get something interesting

Comment: @JannikPitt Did you look at it? It has no useful derivatives, no useful integrals and you can't invert it, you can hardly manipulate it at all, it has no value outside of combinatorics. Even computer scientists wouldn't use it, they use tensor notation and matrices.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Because why wouldn't it? The log(x) deriative and taylor series doesn't have it and I already rewrote the nth derivative of the two-product rule without the combination.

Comment: Your default expectation should be that things don't have nice expressions. Most expressions are ugly.

Comment: Wrong again, my default expectation is it has a representation without a combination or permutation, I wouldn't care if it was pages long.